# NotFoundHttpException - Exception handling not showing the response view Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to handle all the non available routes and redirect them to my `503.blade` view. i.e whenever user enters URL like `//localhost:8000/adbkjabd` or `//localhost:8000/anything-they-like` i want to handle them and show them 503 view. In my `render()` function. It is not redirecting me to the 503 page and still says in the same page with errors.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

        // normal 503 view page feedback
        return response()->view('errors.503', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Am i having a wrong understanding of this or am i making any logical errors ?

Comment: You have to define 'NotFoundHttpException' as 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in top of your **Handler.php**

Comment: that didnt work , i did `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpExceptio‌​n as NotFoundHttpExceptio‌​n;`

Comment: Try debugging $e. Try to find instance of it with get_class() function. You have no errors in your code. You have left to debug it